# SQL procedure to add and edit data

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Im busy with an old exam paper one of the questions read as follows

Study the following tables and answer the questions below:

```
 CREATE TABLE CARDHOLDERS(
    CH_ID INTEGER IDENTITY,
    CH_NAME VARCHAR(50),
    CH_SURNAME VARCHAR(50),
    CH_IDNUMBER CHAR(13),
    CH_CARDNUMBER CHAR(13),
    CH_STATUS CHAR(2),
    CH_CREATE_DATE DATETIME,
    CH_LAST_CHANGE_DATE DATETIME)
```

*Write a store procedure to add or edit the cardholders information. Do the neccecary validation checks to ensure data is correct.*

**My Answer**

```
Create Procedure add_ch (@CH_NAME, @CH_SURNAME...)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CARDHOLDERS VALUES (@CH_NAME, @CH_SURNAME...)
END
```

TO RUN PROCEDURE

```
EXECUTE add_ch ('Peter', 'Kemp')
```

**My Question**

- Will the above procedure to add cardholer give the correct results?
- The Question asks *'Write a store procedure to add or edit the
  cardholders information'* **how do I combine the add procedure with
  the edit cardholder procedure** or am I correct in assuming that I can
  have to different procedure?

Comment: Apologies typo will edit

Comment: I can't see any validation checks in your stored procedure.

Comment: @VMai yes Im stuck on the validation, any suggestions?

Comment: for edits you could pass in the identity column (nullable), if it's invoked with a value do an update, if not do an insert.  You could additionally work in a merge statement to handle either scenario in the same statement

Comment: @Marilee What about `EXECUTE add_ch ('I will tell you the whole history of my family, starting with Adam and Eve and some million other people in between', '+++++++++++++', ...)` This example should suggest two possible checks at least.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_ch (@CH_NAME , @CH_SURNAME...)
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @count   INT

    SET @count =
           (SELECT count (*)
              FROM CARDHOLDERS
             WHERE CH_NAME = @CH_NAME AND CH_SURNAME = @CH_SURNAME)

    IF @count = 0
       INSERT INTO CARDHOLDERS
       VALUES (@CH_NAME, @CH_SURNAME...)

    else Print'This user already exsit.'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Using decode and setting defaults for the parameters helps.

```
create or replace procedure add_ch
(
    CHID INTEGER := -1,
    CHNAME VARCHAR := '@',
    CHSURNAME VARCHAR := '@',
    CHIDNUMBER CHAR := '@',
    CH_CARDNUMBER CHAR := '@',
    CHSTATUS CHAR := '@',
    CHCREATE_DATE DATETIME := '01-Jan-1900',
    CHLAST_CHANGE_DATE DATETIME:= '01-Jan-1900'
)
as
begin
    update cardholders
    set    CH_NAME = decode( CHNAME,'@',CH_NAME,chname ),
           CH_SURNAME = decode( CHSURNAME,'@',CH_SURNAME, CHSURNAME),....
    where  CH_ID = CHID;

    if sql%notfound
    then
        insert into cardholders
        (
           CH_ID,
           CH_NAME,
           CH_SURNAME,
           CH_IDNUMBER,
           CH_CARDNUMBER,
           CH_STATUS,
           CH_CREATE_DATE,
           CH_LAST_CHANGE_DATE
        )
        values
        (
           CHID,
           CHNAME,
           CHSURNAME,
           CHIDNUMBER,
           CH_CARDNUMBER,
           CHSTATUS CHAR,
           CHCREATE_DATE,
           CHLAST_CHANGE_DATE
         );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

**first of all You Have to find The primary key data in your database table**

**if** exist data in **DBtable**(with current primary key value)

then execute your update sql query

**else**
execute your insert query.

Done your database checking using the previous answer to your question.